# How to send a java object to a get method trought angular JS

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have to do a search in a Java server and I needo to pass the parameters as an object. I was passing the search fields as strings using   HttpParams. But now I need to pass it as an object that have 9 strings, because sonar just accept utinl 7 arguments. I need to keep using get method. How can I do it?

here is the signature of the get method in the server:

```
@GetMapping("/buscarPorFiltros")
public ResponseEntity<ProjetoResponse> buscarPorFiltros(PesquisaDTO pesquisa){
}
```

here is PesquisaDTO class:

```
public class PesquisaDTO {

    private Optional<String> dsProjeto;
    private Optional<String> nomeProjeto;
    private Optional<Date> dataInicio;
    private Optional<Date> dataFim;
    private Optional<String> statusProjeto;
    private Optional<String> un;
    private Optional<String> setor;
    private Optional<String> gerenteProjetoNome;
    private Optional<String> serviceType;

   public PesquisaDTO() {
   }

   public String getDsProjeto() {
       return dsProjeto.isPresent() ? dsProjeto.get() : "";
   }

   // others getters similar to getDsProject()
```

here is the angular function:

```
 public buscarPorFiltros(dsProjeto, nomeProjeto, statusProjeto, dtInicio, dtFim, un, setor, gerenteProjetoNome, serviceType): Observable<ProjetoResponse> {

      varpesquisa: Pesquisa;

      if (dsProjeto) {
          pesquisa.dsProjeto = dsProjeto;
      }
      if (nomeProjeto) {
          pesquisa.nomeProjeto = nomeProjeto;
      }
      if (statusProjeto) {
          pesquisa.statusProjeto = statusProjeto;
      }
      if (dtInicio && dtFim) {
          pesquisa.dataInicio = dtInicio;
          pesquisa.dataFim = dtFim;
      }
      if (un) {
         pesquisa.un = un;
      }
      if (setor) {
         pesquisa.setor = setor;
     }

     if (gerenteProjetoNome) {
        pesquisa.gerenteProjetoNome = gerenteProjetoNome;
     }

     if (serviceType){
        pesquisa.serviceType = serviceType;
     }

      return this.httpClient.get<ProjetoResponse>(this.applicationUrl + mappingUrls.projetoService.buscarPorFiltros, { pesquisa });

 }
```

The Angular isn't accepting 'pesquisa' as parameter 
Its says:

```
Argument of type '{ pesquisa: Pesquisa; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pesquisa' does not exist in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: sure, with `GET` we don't send body. You mean to use `POST`?

Comment: sorry, but I have to use get method because is a search. I edited my question. I think it is more clear now.

Comment: then you probably want to set them like `HttpParams`: https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-the-request

Comment: If you want to send a large dto as a request body, you have to use post. Get standards do not support this. Either use httpParams, or change to post. Why do you **have** to use get?

Comment: Can I transform the angular object in a string using JSON.stringify and then receive this string as parameter of my get method in  server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side :

```
@GetMapping("/buscarPorFiltros")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ProjetoResponse> buscarPorFiltros(String pesquisa ){
    try {
        String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(pesquisa, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PesquisaDTO pesquisaDto = mapper.readValue(result, PesquisaDTO.class);
```

On Client side:

```
  const params = new HttpParams().set("pesquisa", encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(pesquisa)));
  return this.httpClient.get<ProjetoResponse>(this.applicationUrl + mappingUrls.projetoService.buscarPorFiltros, {params});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HttpParams` Agular class to build your url string with request params like that:

```
 public buscarPorFiltros(dsProjeto, nomeProjeto, statusProjeto, dtInicio, dtFim, un, setor, gerenteProjetoNome, serviceType): Observable<ProjetoResponse> {
  const requestParams = new HttpParams();

  if (dsProjeto) {
      requestParams.append('dsProjeto', dsProjeto);
  }
  if (nomeProjeto) {
      requestParams.append('nomeProjeto', nomeProjeto);
  }
  if (statusProjeto) {
      requestParams.append('statusProjeto', statusProjeto);
  }
  if (dtInicio && dtFim) {
      requestParams.append('dtInicio', dtInicio);
      requestParams.append('dtFim', dtFim);
  }
  if (un) {
     requestParams.append('un', un);
  }
  if (setor) {
     requestParams.append('setor', setor);
 }

 if (gerenteProjetoNome) {
     requestParams.append('gerenteProjetoNome', gerenteProjetoNome);
 }

 if (serviceType){
     requestParams.append('serviceType', serviceType);
 }

  return this.httpClient.get<ProjetoResponse>(this.applicationUrl + mappingUrls.projetoService.buscarPorFiltros, requestParams);
}
```

And on the server side you need to have controller like you have now:

```
@GetMapping("/buscarPorFiltros")
public ResponseEntity<ProjetoResponse> buscarPorFiltros(PesquisaDTO pesquisa){
}
```

Also `PesquisaDTO` needs to have set/get methods to each field, then Spring will be convert http get params to `PesquisaDTO` object.